# How to convert Prometheus queries to Datadog

Tags: prometheus, datadog

Due to a migration from Prometheus/Grafana to Datadog we need to recreate/export our existing dashboards to Datadog.

I've tried to find a solution to ease this migration or at least any good examples of re-creating equivalent queries from Prom to DataDog.

For example, what would be the equivalent for this query:
`round(sum(increase(app_sync_failure_total{schedule=~\"$schedule\"}[1h])))`

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should work:

```
round(sum:app_sync_failure_total{schedule:$schedule}.as_count().rollup('1h').sum)
```

Comment: are you aware of any module/API in any language which will help in converting Prometheus queries to Datadog please?